# Partial ID selectors with webdriverjs.io and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to build some test automation scripts for Salesforce. http://webdriver.io/ seems very easy to use. Now I want to add jQuery into the mix.

I want to be able to perform a partial id select which I know I can do with jQuery

Here is my script file

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs'); 
var $ = require('jquery');
var client = webdriverjs.remote({ 
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
});

client.init();

client
    .url('https://xxx.cs17.force.com')
    .setValue( $('input[id*=username]') ,'x@x.com.envd', function(err,result) {});
```

Here is what my id string looks like[image]

My questions are

1. How can I use jQuery - getting this error "Error: jQuery requires a window with a document", or
2. Is there another way to find my IDs

Comment: Have you tried to use an xpath selector? In your dev tools right click on the element and copy xpath

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to necessarily refer to the id to interact with an element. You can use also other [selector strategies](https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs#selector-api) like standard css selectors or xpath.

Try to do a right click on the element you want to interact with and then click on "Copy CSS Path" or "Copy XPath". Replace this with your current jQuery implementation:

```
client
    .url('https://xxx.cs17.force.com')
    .setValue('//some/xpath' ,'x@x.com.envd')
```

One the on hand xPath is really slow but it provides extended selector options you can use in case you don't know anything about the element classname or ID.